# Transfer data from Kafka Topic to a UDP and TCP Port

Tags: sockets, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I try to transfer data from [tag:Kafka to [udp](/questions/tagged/udp) or [tcp](/questions/tagged/tcp) port.
I tried to find a [apache-kafka-connect](/questions/tagged/apache-kafka-connect) to achieve this goal, but I couldn't find anything related.
Do you have any suggestion to find the best way to create such a pipeline?

Comment: why do you want this?

Comment: @user253751 , customer needs to receive the logs in the kafka topic via a UDP/TCP port

Comment: How does customer know that all the logs are delivered with no gaps? If the connection is broken how does the customer know they haven't got duplicated logs or missing logs?

Comment: @user253751 you mentioned a valid concern, but unfortunately they don't care and they want to have it as an Option

Comment: you can use vector.dev tool. I think  its the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Benthos](https://www.benthos.dev/) for this. E.g.

```
input:
  label: "Kafka Data"
  kafka:
    addresses: ["localhost:9092"]
    topics: ["input"]
    target_version: 2.0.0
    consumer_group: "example"
output:
  label: "Socket Out"
  socket:
    network: "tcp" # or udp
    address: "host:1234"
    codec: lines
```

Comment: Do you have any idea about it's performance on transfering huge data?

Comment: You'd have to do your own benchmarks